# Having trouble connecting to a web service with a windows 8.1 phone app

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone

This is my first time doing something like this so I'm probably going to sound stupid but here it goes.

Here is my method that is supposed to connect to the web service.

```
public async void getWebData()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9011/Service.svc?singleWsdl");
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        // Always catch network exceptions for async methods
        try
        {
            var result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);

            doSomething(result);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Details in ex.Message and ex.HResult.       
        }

        // Once your app is done using the HttpClient object call dispose to 
        // free up system resources (the underlying socket and memory used for the object)
        httpClient.Dispose();
    }
```

Here is my config info from the web.config file where I believe I added the rest endpoint correctly because I read that you have to use a rest endpoint to access web services in windows 8.1 phone apps.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpBinding_IService" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:9011/Service.svc?singleWsdl" name="rest"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IService" contract="WcfService.IService" />
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:9011/Service.svc?singleWsdl" name="soap"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="WcfService.IService" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong to access my webservice because nothing I try has been working...

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: I'm not receiving an exception. I inserted a breakpoint at the result line and it never hits the breakpoint

Comment: Are you new to C# and Web Service ? Because as per your web.config you should have to use proxy class but you are directly access wsdl in your code. Another suggestion is to try without async and await.

Comment: follow this sample: http://prathapk.net/consuming-wcf-service-in-windows-phone-application/

Comment: I'm not new to C# but I'm brand new to web services

Comment: That sample doesn't apply to my problem because I'm creating a windows 8.1 app and they don't support adding web references for some stupid reason. Check this link to see what I'm talking about   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/06fc8c48-3d85-4867-82e7-517f1ba68256/wcf-add-service-reference-not-supported-for-windows-phone-81-xaml-applications?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but you sure you can hit `localhost` from the phone/emulator? Don't know if it will really recognizes. Because `localhost` is always `Me`.

Comment: Yes I'm able to connect to the localhost. Before I made the endpoint changes, it allowed me to connect with the http client and I saw all of the data but didn't know what to do with it. Did you see the link that I posted?